# Size of local-chromium

Tags: puppeteer

Installing puppeteer installs a local-chromium which is of size 292MB.
Generating PDF with HTML is the only feature that I'm using with puppeteer for now.
Is there a way to lower the size of npm?

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce half of the size be deleting "interactive_ui_tests.exe", it seems something that you don't need to run Puppeteer correctly. I do it on my daily scenarios with no problems.

There is also a discussion about this on [Github](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/842)